# HTML form with dynamic action (using JavaScript?)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, action

I want to create a form like this:

1. Type in your ID number into the form's input and submit.
2. The form's action becomes something like `/account/{id}/`.

I was told JavaScript was the only way to achieve this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052290/html-form-method-with-nice-url)), but how?

Comment: i think you are looking to do a GET request like account.php?id=33 ?

Comment: No, I'm looking to do a POST request like `account/33`

Comment: just because you mentioned w3schools: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it might look something like this:

```
$('#inputAccount').change(function () {
    $('#myForm').attr('action', 'http://www.example.com/account/' + $('#inputAccount').val());
});
```

This should change the action of the form any time the text in the input element changes.  You could also use `.blur()` instead of `.change()` to perform the action whenever focus leaves the input element, so it doesn't keep changing all the time, etc.  Then, when the form is submitted, it should submit to whatever was last placed in its action attribute.

Comment: I'd suggest blur in this case. Potential infinite loop, right?

Comment: @D_N: Perhaps not an infinite loop, but I think you may be right that blur would be best.  The only problem I'd see with blur would be if some browsers submitted the form on return press from within the input element without technically leaving the element.

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(frm.txt).keyup(function(){
            $(frm).get(0).setAttribute('action', '/account/'+$(frm.txt).val());
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm" action="foo">
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="do eet" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't see why not.. Give it a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in JavaScript. Depending on the checked radio button (in this case,but it could be another form element) it will be chosen an action or the other:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm()
{
  if(document.myform.operation[0].checked == true)
  {
    document.myform.action ="insert.html";
  }
  else
  if(document.myform.operation[1].checked == true)
  {
    document.myform.action ="update.html";
  }
  return true;
}
</script>

<form name="myform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
   name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" checked>insert
   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="2">update
   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
   </p>
</form>
```